# Extending PageDrawer in pdfbox 2.0.x

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to do some custom rendering by extending the PageDrawer class in Apache PDFBox 2.0.x.
In the comments it is mentioned that we should subclass PageDrawer class for custom rendering. But, the constructor of PageDrawer expects parameters which cannot be created out of the package.

Is there any way to overcome this? Has anyone done subclassing of PageDrawer in PDFBox 2.0.x?

Comment: There is no PDFDrawer class.

Comment: Oops - I meant PageDrawer - sorry - will update the question

Comment: I suspect you'll need to subclass PDFRenderer as well.

Comment: Was going to mention that. I was able to solve it by subclassing PDFRenderer and modifying createPageDrawer method. Thank you very much, Tilman.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I'll clarify the comment some time this weekend. Consider answering the question yourself (this is allowed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that PageDrawer alone cannot be subclassed. Rather, a custom PDFRenderer class was created where we can set our custom PageDrawer by overriding the createPageDrawer method.

Comment: hm, but createPageDrawer still needs PageDrawerParameters which is package level 